# Why are my Imperial assignment rewards not appearing?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have been having an issue with Imperial assignments:

1. After finishing an Imperial assignment, the assignment is auto-replaced with a new one, but the reward doesn't appear?
2. I have been stockpiling unneeded imperial resources ahead of time, but they seem to disappear from my inventory randomly?

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, do they know why this is happening, and/or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>Answer from the OP, originally posted in the comments</sub>

---

In regards to the second point: I thought that I was building items at the medal rate. I was looking for 2-5 items built at once.

Instead, I should have been looking for 1 item built at once, with 2-5 medals.